# Do I need to style a section tag for backwards compatibility?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to jump on the HTML5 bandwagon now that it's gotten more coverage and is a mature spec.

---

Instead of using a div tag for this:

```
<div class="page-item">
    <h2>Google rumored to purchase WhatsApp for $1 Billion dollars.</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi 
        in felis nisi, quis vulputate odio. Proin eu est dolor, non 
        feugiat dui. Cras tristique, arcu nec adipiscing varius, nibh 
        dolor fermentum nibh, in elementum justo dolor et enim. Nullam 
        libero dui, tristique ut pulvinar at, consequat malesuada nisl. 
        Vestibulum sed elit purus, id posuere neque. Pellentesque luctus 
        libero quis risus ullamcorper sollicitudin. Pellentesque dictum, 
        est et blandit placerat, mi erat tempus diam, et aliquet ipsum felis 
        sit amet risus. Proin pretium accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque vel 
        tortor lacus, sit amet aliquam mi. Donec tincidunt ullamcorper 
        molestie.</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to use a `section` tag:

```
<section>
    <h2>Google rumored to purchase WhatsApp for $1 Billion dollars.</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi 
        in felis nisi, quis vulputate odio. Proin eu est dolor, non 
        feugiat dui. Cras tristique, arcu nec adipiscing varius, nibh 
        dolor fermentum nibh, in elementum justo dolor et enim. Nullam 
        libero dui, tristique ut pulvinar at, consequat malesuada nisl. 
        Vestibulum sed elit purus, id posuere neque. Pellentesque luctus 
        libero quis risus ullamcorper sollicitudin. Pellentesque dictum, 
        est et blandit placerat, mi erat tempus diam, et aliquet ipsum felis 
        sit amet risus. Proin pretium accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque vel 
        tortor lacus, sit amet aliquam mi. Donec tincidunt ullamcorper 
        molestie.</p>
</section>
```

What sort of styling do I need to apply so this `section` tag works as well as possible for old-ish browsers? (*IE7 onwards*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as styling, that is CSS, is concerned, you need only do a basic reset of specific HTML5 elements like so: `section{display: block;}`

But, in order for older browsers, like IE7 for example, to actually recognize the new elements  as, well, elements indeed, you need to register them as such. The short, easy, and certainly to the point way of doing this is via Javascript, by adding `document.createElement("section");` in a script declaration in the page's `<head>`.

All of the stuff above you can find as part of the [HTML5 Starter Pack](http://sickdesigner.com/resources/HTML5-starter-pack/index.html) which is meant to aid developers in starting up their HTML5 projects.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know. But, hey, you know the old saying: haters gonna hate!  :) It doesn't matter, anyway, just hope you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First off I think you should be using `<h1>` as the first header of `<section>`, though someone can correct me.

IE8- do not support these tags at all and will ignore any styles associated with them.  There are two fairly simple solutions.  One is to add

```
document.createElement('section');
```

Before the `<section>` element appears.  Then, IE applies the styles for some reason.  There are plenty of HTML5 shims/shivs out there that will do this for all new elements.

If you can't rely on JS or don't want to do this for some reason, you can always keep the `<div>` for styling and just keep the `<section>` for semantics.  It doesn't hurt to have the `<div>` there since it has no semantic meaning other than grouping elements, which the `<section>` also does.

Comment: `h1` tags are reserved to the lead main header of a document. Since I intend to have many of these sections on a single document, having an `h2` makes more sense.

Comment: @Serg are you sure?  Read this section: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#headings-and-sections